# How to generate aggregated serenity testing report in parallel jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins

We are running Jenkins declarative pipeline in parallel for diversity testing scenarios and using serenity to generate testing reports. Currently, we should check different testing report according to specific testing scenarios (for example, 10 testing scenarios with 10 serenity reports). Now we would like to generate only 1 aggregated report. How to configure in the pipeline? Please revert me if any more info you need. Thanks for anyone's help.

```
pipeline {
agent { node ("cm-linux") }
stages {
    stage('run-parallel-regression-testing') {
        steps {
            parallel(
                Run1_LoginPage: {
                  node('cm-windows'){
                  withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${tool '1.8.0.65_Windows'}", "PATH+MAVEN=${tool 'maven-3.0.4'}/bin"]){
                    deleteDir()
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: '*/Ted']],
                    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                    extensions: [],
                    gitTool: 'GIT_windows',
                    submoduleCfg: [],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<Credential>',
                    url: '<GITHUB ADDRESS>']]])
                  bat 'mvn clean -Dtest=Run1_LoginPage -Dwebdriver.remote.url="<seleniumgrid hub address>" verify'
                    publishHTML([allowMissing: false,
                    alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
                    keepAll: true,
                    reportDir: 'target\\site\\serenity',
                    reportFiles: 'index.html',
                    reportName: 'Run1_LoginPage'])
                          }
                      }
                  },
                Run2_SearchTab: {
                  node('cm-windows'){
                  withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${tool '1.8.0.65_Windows'}", "PATH+MAVEN=${tool 'maven-3.0.4'}/bin"]){
                    deleteDir()
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: '*/Ted']],
                    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                    extensions: [],
                    gitTool: 'GIT_windows',
                    submoduleCfg: [],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<credential id>',
                    url: '<github address>']]])
                  bat 'mvn clean -Dtest=Run2_SearchTab -Dwebdriver.remote.url="<seleniumgrid hub address>" verify'
                    publishHTML([allowMissing: false,
                    alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
                    keepAll: true,
                    reportDir: 'target\\site\\serenity',
                    reportFiles: 'index.html',
                    reportName: 'Run2_SearchTab'])
                        }
                    }
                },

                Run4_AccountTab: {
                  node('cm-windows'){
                  withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${tool '1.8.0.65_Windows'}", "PATH+MAVEN=${tool 'maven-3.0.4'}/bin"]){
                    deleteDir()
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: '*/Ted']],
                    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                    extensions: [],
                    gitTool: 'GIT_windows',
                    submoduleCfg: [],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<credential id>',
                    url: '<github address>']]])
                  bat 'mvn clean -Dtest=Run4_AccountTab -Dwebdriver.remote.url="<seleniumgrid hub address>" verify'
                    publishHTML([allowMissing: false,
                    alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
                    keepAll: true,
                    reportDir: 'target\\site\\serenity',
                    reportFiles: 'index.html',
                    reportName: 'Run4_AccountTab'])
                            }
                        }
                    },
                Run3_CustomerTab: {
                  node('cm-windows'){
                  withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${tool '1.8.0.65_Windows'}", "PATH+MAVEN=${tool 'maven-3.0.4'}/bin"]){
                    deleteDir()
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: '*/Ted']],
                    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                    extensions: [],
                    gitTool: 'GIT_windows',
                    submoduleCfg: [],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<credential id>',
                    url: '<github address>']]])
                  bat 'mvn clean -Dtest=Run3_CustomerTab -Dwebdriver.remote.url="<seleniumgrid hub address>" verify'
                    publishHTML([allowMissing: false,
                    alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
                    keepAll: true,
                    reportDir: 'target\\site\\serenity',
                    reportFiles: 'index.html',
                    reportName: 'Run3_CustomerTab'])
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/serenity-parallel.html#_configuring_parallel_batch_execution_with_jenkins_2_dsl

by stashing the partial results and unstashing them one by one at the end, you get a folder with all test results copied together.

What is missing in this example is the aggregation step. You have to run
"mvn serenity:aggregate"
before publishing the report. It merges all single test results in the overview page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it works for me. Thank you very much.